# How to escape string so it can be parsed as Python code to give original string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When generating Python code by a Python script, there is a string in `s` from which a line of Python code should be generated with the behavior of `t = '...'`, with generation by:

```
code_t_assign = "t = '{}'".format(s)
```

The initial `s` can for example be `'\"`, where proper escaping should then make code like:

```
t = '\'\\"'
```

What is the safe way to escape special characters like `\` and `'` in `s` to the code line for assign of `t` can execute?

Comment: Couldn't understand the problem clearly. What is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: `s` can never be `'\ ` - no string can end in a single backslash. Did you mean that `print(s)` would output `'\ `?

Comment: I believe you might be looking for [`repr(s)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr).

Answer (score 1):

Based on comment from @LukasGraf:

```
code_t_assign = "t = {}".format(repr(s))
```

Resulting in code as:

```
t = '\'\\"'
```